# Can boto3 reuse HTTPS connections?

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, aws-lambda, boto3

Viewing the log from my lambda function, I've noticed that there will often be items like this:

```
[1481151396619] [INFO]  2016-12-07T22:56:36.619Z    Starting new HTTPS connection (1): abc.execute-api.us.amazonaws.com
[1481151397217] [INFO]  2016-12-07T22:56:37.217Z    Starting new HTTPS connection (1): abc.execute-api.us.amazonaws.com
```

where a call is being made to the same service twice in less than a minute, but it says it is starting a new connection each time. Is it possible to reuse a connection that's already been established? Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: Code required !